# Regex to group Zip Code , City and State

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string

> "98225-2077 Bellingham WA"

I need to use Regex to separate Zip Code, City and State.
the groups should return 
(98225-2077)(Bellingham) and (WA).
The State is optional and will always be at the end and will consist of two Uppercase charachters.

I am able to filter out the following using regex

Zip Code : `(^([\S]+-)?\d+(-\d+)?)` - Group[1]
City: `((^([\S]+-)?\d+(-\d+)?)\s)?(\S.*)` = Group[5].

Can there be a single regex to filter out all the three using the same regex and return blank in case the state is not there?

Comment: City name can also be of more than one word . Example New Delhi.

Comment: Great...thanks for telling me this now

Comment: The only way of parsing is regex which is stored in the Db according to the design

Comment: [`(\d+-\d+)\s+(.*?)(?:\s+([A-Z]+)$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cd%2b-%5cd%2b)%5cs%2b(.*%3f)(%3f%3a%5cs%2b(%5bA-Z%5d%2b)%24)&i=98225-2077+New+Dehli+WA).

Comment: Doesnt group for "98225-2077 Bellingham". Please post it in the answers section so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: I don't think regex is the best way to go here.

Comment: @SJMan, I do not think you need a regex, unless you need to also (pre-)validate the string or extract it from a large text.

Comment: Well, perhaps `(\d+-\d+)\s+(.*?)(?:\s+([A-Z]+))?$` can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for just splitting the string on space and then using the various parts as you need.  Because your city name may consist of multiple words, I iterate from the second to next-to-last element to build the city name.  This solution assumes that the zip code and state two abbreviation will always be single words.

```
string address = "98225-2077 Bellingham WA";
string[] tokens = address.Split(' ');

string city = "";
for (int i=1; i < tokens.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (i > 1)
    {
        city += " ";
    }
    city += tokens[i];
}

Console.WriteLine("zip code: {0}", tokens[0]);
Console.WriteLine("city: {0}", city);
Console.WriteLine("state: {0}", tokens[tokens.Length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
^([\d-]+)\s+(.+?)\s*([A-Z]{2})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/tL4tN5/1

Explanation:

1. `^([\d-]+)`: `^` is for the very beginning of the string. `\d` for digits
2. `\s+(.+?)\s*`: Get anything in the middle between ZIP code and state
3. `([A-Z]{2})?$`: `{2}` means 2 character in the specified range `[A-Z]`. `?` means it exists 1 or 0 times.

Comment: the state can or cannot be there. I am working off c#

Comment: Yup, it can work without state. I update the regex a little bit to be more accurate. please review

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
^(\d[\d-]+)\s+(.*?)(?:\s+([A-Z]{2}))?$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP2kA1/2)**

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/xMNy1n)**

Answer (score 0):

I really think you can do it without a regex. Here are two solutions:

**Non-regex solution**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Split address into ZIP, Description/Street/anything, [A-Z]{2} state
/// </summary>
/// <returns>null if no space is found</returns>
public static List<string> SplitZipAnyStateAddress(this string s)
{
    if (!s.Contains(' ')) return null;
    var zip = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' '));
    var state = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    var middle = s.Substring(zip.Length + 1, s.Length - state.Length - zip.Length - 2);
    return state.Length == 2 && state.All(p => Char.IsUpper(p)) ? 
        new List<string>() { zip, middle, state } : 
        new List<string>() { zip, string.Format("{0} {1}", middle, state) };
}
```

Results:

```
StringRegUtils.SplitZipAnyStateAddress("98225-2077 Bellingham WA");
// => [0] 98225-2077 [1] Bellingham [2] WA
StringRegUtils.SplitZipAnyStateAddress("98225-2077 Bellin gham");
// => [0] 98225-2077 [1] Bellin gham
StringRegUtils.SplitZipAnyStateAddress("98225-2077 New Delhi CA");
// => [0] 98225-2077 [1] New Delhi [2] CA
```

**REGEX**

If not, you can use my intial regex suggestion (I think a `?` got lost):

```
^(?<zip>\d+-\d+)\s+(?<city>.*?)(?:\s+(?<state>[A-Z]{2}))?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Czip%3E%5Cd%2B-%5Cd%2B)%5Cs%2B(%3F%3Ccity%3E.*%3F)(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B(%3F%3Cstate%3E%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D))%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=98225-2077%20New%20Dehli%20WA%0D%0A98225-2077%20New%20Dehli&o=m)

Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<zip>\d+-\d+)` - 1+ digits followed with `-` followed with 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<city>.*?)` - 0+ characters other than a newline as few as possible up to the
- `(?:\s+(?<state>[A-Z]{2}))?` - optional (1 or 0) occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?<state>[A-Z]{2})` - exactly 2 uppercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string